# To store value as xml format in a column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table called `User` with a column `Orders`.. `Orders` will contain `orderID` of the user.. Single user can have multiple `OrderID`'s so I need to store multiple values in one column using xml.. Need to store like this in a column

```
<Orders>
    <OrderID>45586</OrderID>
    <OrderID>45578</OrderID>
</Orders>
```

How to do that using a stored procedure or C# code and need to add child node at the end if new order placed

Pls help guys...

Comment: Normally you do not store M:N relations in a single column but in a bridge table with UserID and OrderID.

Comment: ***Don't do this!*** This is a ***horribly bad*** design. Use a proper way - using an M:N relationship with a "link" table between users and orders. This approach is flawed from the start - you ***will*** regret it down the line! Stop and redesign your approach

Comment: Or choose a real document database (MongoDB, RavenDB, and many more) if you don't need the relational model.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #temp(val varchar(100) )
insert into #temp(val) values (
cast
((
SELECT 
    1 as a,2 as b,3 as c

    FOR
    XML PATH('Fruits'),
    TYPE)
 as varchar(100)))
select * from #temp
```

Comment: @ Janty Yours is Nice solution but it returns `VARCHAR` value only in the form of XML when we select the value in the table.So, I had changed the `CAST` to `CONVERT` and converted the datatype of the variable from `VARCHAR` to `XML`

Answer (score 0):

Aside from don't do it to your database, normalize first, this is syntax how to modify in SQL SERVER 2005 and higher environment

```
    declare @xml xml
    declare @newElement xml
    select @xml = '<Orders>
        <OrderID>45586</OrderID>
        <OrderID>45578</OrderID>
    </Orders>'

    select @newElement = '<OrderID>12</OrderID>'

    set @xml.modify(
    'insert sql:variable("@newElement")
    as last into (//Orders)[1]'
    )

    select @xml
```